# LibreOffice Base in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: Screenshot showing too small database number field

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

If I ask LibreOffice base to show me the result of a query, the resulting screen will show the total number of datasets and the number of the currently selected dataset on the bottom left. However, the field to show the currently selected dataset is way too small.

I have a standard Ubuntu 12.04 installation with its standard theme and its standard libreoffice base running. One work-around is to change the theme to "Ambience". I however would like to stay with the standard theme.

I posted this question in the libreoffice forum. They told me I should ask here.

This is how it looks:

[image: here]

Comment: Can you not click and drag the line between them?